# How do I access to React Component API from created ReactElement?

Tags: reactjs

```
class Component extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div/>;
    }
}
var view = <Component foo="bar"/>;
```

How do I access to `Component`'s methods? Something like `view.Component.forceUpdate()`?

Comment: You shouldn't need to. Could you edit your question to describe what you're trying to do?

Comment: It's need when I trying to subscribe my view on model change event in controller.

Comment: You should propagate the change through components and/or use setState. using forceUpdate shouldn't be used in the scenario you described.

Comment: Ok, How do I run `setState` method in this case?

Comment: When the callback happens for the model change, call `setState`.  The event listener should have the context of the React component.

Answer (score 0):

Flux (and its variants) is the architecture used in most React applications.

A unidirectional data flow is central to the Flux pattern. React components should receive all data and callbacks needed via props.

If it needs to trigger an action, its props should contain the `dispatch` object or action creators.

If the container component needs to get the internal state of view components, the container component should provide a callback to get updated when a state of view component is changed.